# Custom cursor move with window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to code a custom cursor in jquery/css - I've got it working fine, my only issue is that if you scroll without moving the mouse the cursor loses it's position.

https://jsfiddle.net/pxo7ycb5/1/

I've tried adding a window scroll event to no avail also. Is there a workaround for this?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){
    $('#test').css({
       left:  e.pageX,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you'll have to rework that a bit so you're using a fixed element.  Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/pxo7ycb5/2/

Comment: @ntgCleaner Your js fiddle still loses it's position after scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making your circle `position:absolute;`, you'll have to change it to `position:fixed;`.  Then add your body scrollTop to the CSS top, like so:

```
#test {
    position: fixed;
    ...
}


$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#test').css({
        left:  e.pageX,
        top:   e.pageY - $('body').scrollTop()
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxo7ycb5/2/

Comment: The first answer works fine and not this one .

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, you still lost your cursor because you used `e.pageX`. 
You should change it to `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`.

```
#test {
    position: fixed;
    ...
}


$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    $('#test').css({
       left:  e.clientX,
       top:   e.clientY,
    });
});

$(window).on('scroll', function(e){ ... });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/elvinci/pxo7ycb5/14/

Comment: Thank you for this!